# how to start checking String from back if contains a specific letter

Tags: java, string

How to find a `.` from back to front in string

```
String calc = "abcd+abcd.abcd+abcd-abcd.abcd"

for (int i = calc.length(); i > 0; i--) {
    if (calc.charAt(i) == '.') {
      //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into the overloaded `indexOf` method.

Comment: Didn't you just answered your own question? My apologies. It seems there is a index out of bounds error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost correct, I believe you want -

```
// for (int i = calc.length(); i > 0; i--) {
for (int i = calc.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // <-- 0 is the first character.
```

Comment: `// <-- start counting at 0.` Did you mean `stop counting at 0` or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: It's also good to get into the habit of using the precrement operator `--i`  rather than the post-decrement operator `i--`

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley Can you please explain that statement?

Comment: @DavidWallace pre-decrement?

Comment: Yeah, I too would like an explanation of why one is better than the other.  Can't see it myself.

Comment: I know most compilers optimise out the difference, but traditionally the post-decrement `i--` will keep a copy of the original value of `i` while the pre-decrement `--i` will not. `x = --i` will return `i-1` and update `i`, but `x = i--` will update `i` to `i-1` and then return the original value of `i`

Comment: You mean on the stack, or in a CPU register?